# Recursive async function not returning a value

Tags: javascript, recursion, async-await

I have the following code, which runs ok to certain extend. However at the last stage, the function is supposed to return a value which I'm not getting.

```js
let sleep = function(ms) {
    return new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('[DELAYED_PROCESS] completed.');
            resolve('data_stream');
        }, ms);
    });
}

class RequestHandler {
    #isBusy = false;
    #size = 9;

    constructor(name=null) {
        this.name = name == null ? 'handler_' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) : 'handler_' + name;
        this.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
        console.log(`created handler with NAME: ${this.name} and ID: ${this.id}`);
    }

    async processQueue() {
        this.#isBusy = true;
        console.log(this.#size);
        try{
            let task = await sleep(2000);
            console.log(`Data received. ${this.#size}`);
        }catch(e){
            console.log(`Data failed. ${this.#size}`);
            console.log('continue ...');
        }

        // Reduce Size
        this.#size -= 1;

        // Queue is consumed, we are done.
        if (this.#size==0) {
            console.log('... done ...');
            this.#isBusy = false;
            return 'DONE';
        } else {
            console.log('... next ...');
            await this.processQueue();
        }
    };
}

const myHandler = new RequestHandler('banana');

console.log('[1] This task relies on the response being received ... (working)');

(async () => {
    let response = await myHandler.processQueue()
    console.log(`[1] result: ${response}`);
    console.log('[1] Done.');
})();

console.log('[2] Some other task running.');
console.log('[2] Some other task is done.');
```

How can I figure out what is wrong?

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: Also, why use recursion here? You're basically just iterating anyway.

Comment: It doesn't return anything because you are not using `return` on the outcome of `await this.processQueue()`.

Comment: Why `let task = await sleep()` when neither the return value of `sleep()` nor the content of `task` is of any interest?

Comment: `sleep()` is returning `data_stream` but even if I do `return task` I still get `undefined`.

Comment: I'm just trying to return something once the recursive iteration is complete.

Comment: @Ivar No, I'm returning a value out of my function.

Comment: @mbilyanov I'm not sure what you mean by that comment. If I replace `await this.processQueue();` with `return this.processQueue();` it returns `'DONE'` just fine.

Comment: @Ivar Thank you. It seems that is the solution to my problem. I thought that the function needs to call itself until the last stage before finally returning something.

Comment: @mbilyanov A function only returns something if you use `return`. If the first invocation of `processQueue()` ends up in the else-branch, it wont return anything.

Comment: @Ivar The problem is a lot deeper than that. There is a `return` and one can use return and exit the function at any level, even if it is recursive. The issue here is because `async` uses `Promises` under the hood, the next iteration of the function requires the function call to be returned. - Anyway, thanks for pointing out that.

Comment: I'm not completely following you. The issue here has little to do with promises and `async/await`. If your function were completely synchronous it would have the same result and the same solution (using `return`). See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chr80dt3/) for a sync version of your code. It is also `undefined` there. If you add the `return` in front of the `this.processQueue()` in the else-branch it will be fixed there as well.

Comment: Sure. You are right. I don't know what I was thinking. I guess ... I was confused. Probably because I did not have to deal with returns the last time I used recursions.